# AutoCompleteTextView adapter issue

Tags: android

I have an AutoCompleteTextView, and depending from the changes in it, it shows the dropdown list with the data from server. Via listener after changing every symbol I make request to the server and take some list.

After that I show that list in AutoCompleteTextView,  in code I do it by this way:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    list.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
}
String[] cities = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DistanceCalculation.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cities);
AutoCompleteTextView my = (AutoCompleteTextView) myView;
my.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Problem** is it oftenly shows only the first element of the list, and after long click it shows the full list. I don understand why its happening.

Sorry for the bad eng, thanks in advance! Also you could check the rest of the code below:

xml part:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
 android:id="@+id/from"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
 android:background="@drawable/td_inp"
 android:hint="Откуда"
 android:paddingBottom="5dp"
 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
 android:paddingRight="5dp"
 android:paddingTop="5dp"
 android:textColor="#000"
 android:textColorHint="#757575" />
```

AutoCompleteTextView and its listener in onCreate

```
tCityFrom = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.from);
tCityFrom.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.length() >= 2) load_city(ssid, s.toString(),tCityFrom);
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more code please ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam, could you check it pls?

Comment: What does your load_city() do ? Can I ask to add that method too ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam, its just simple async for getting data from server,  I m sure that it gets right data, the first code that I posted is the final part of that method(postExecute() of load_city) , also I m sure that problem is related with the setting ready data to autocompletetextview(the same first code, I think that smth is wrong with adapter)

Comment: Check my answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to show AutoComplete suggestions according to what user types. You have to load data from server `onTextChanged()`:

```
tCityFrom = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.from);
tCityFrom.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(s.length() >= 2) 
            load_city(ssid, s.toString(),tCityFrom);
   }
});
```

Then declare **ArrayList** and **Adapter** globally:

```
List<String> list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

In `onCreate()`:

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DistanceCalculation.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cities);
AutoCompleteTextView my = (AutoCompleteTextView) myView;
my.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Replace** your first code snippet of `load_city()` with below code :

```
list.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    list.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope this helps.